# db2 improve performance of coalesce function

Tags: performance, db2

Our system has some performance problems about db2 database.
Recently we found some SQL may cost too much time to execute.
The following one is a simple case

```
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = coalesce(b.code2,b.code1);
```

It costs about 1 second,while if I replace "coalesce(b.code2,b.code1)" with "b.code1",
it will be 10 times faster.(addition:the table2.code2 only have null value).

In some complex statement, it will be 40 seconds compare to 1 second.

But it will be better if there is a way that can improve the performance while keeping code2 there in case it will be not null in future.
I tried create indexes on each column,but it seems no improve at all.
I also tried some condition expression replace of coalesce function,and it costs the same

Comment: You can't really improve the performance of `COALESCE(...)` - it's essentially a `CASE` statement checking for the first non-null value (okay, some dbs provide `IFNULL(...)`, which may be slightly faster if the columns include functions or computations, but not relevant here).  The problem in this case is that you're removing the ability for the optimizer to use indices for the given columns, so your best bet is to do this some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything other than an Equi-join is going to perform worse than an Equi-join; Even though you are using equality operator, the use of coalesce disqualifies it as an Equi-join.

Do you have an index on table2 (code2, code1)?  If not, it would probably help.

You could try a union of two Equi-joins

First thought

```
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code2
UNION ALL
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code1 and b.code2 is NULL;
```

Alternatives

```
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code2
UNION ALL
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code1 
where b.code2 is NULL;
```

Using UNION instead of UNION ALL forces the DB to remove duplicate rows.

```
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code2
UNION
select * from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.code = b.code1;
```

The following index may or may not be of any use (depending on the statement used and the data):

- table2 (code2)
- table2 (code1)
- table2 (code1,code2)

Comment: The multiple `JOINs` with indexes would have been the first thing I would have used. (The logic of the problem table definitions doesn't seem to make good sense though.)

Comment: Thanks.The union all statement executes much faster

Comment: I believe DB2 will generate the same execution plans for the first query and the first alternative.  Certainly the plans are semantically the same.  The other alternative here is something with an `OR` condition (which optimizers don't usually prefer, but will still likely be faster than the use of `COALESCE(...)`).